# Losing default input after adding mask to inputText

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, mask

I'm trying to make a mask to Date and a mask to Hour but i've got an issue. This way, works fine the mask. But stops working the default input that was set on Controller.

```
public class someController {
    String date = "Date";
    String time = "Time";
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

I use jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js for doing this.

```
<div class="someClass">
    <h:inputText id="d" styleClass="clear-field date" value="#{someController.date}"/>
    <h:inputText id="t" styleClass="clear-field time" value="#{someController.time}"/>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
    $(".date").mask("99/99/9999");
    $(".time").mask("99:99");
    });
</script>
```

Any other way to insert a mask to a field and don't lose the default input?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed it!
I've inserted this code above:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
    $(".date").mask("99/99/9999");
    $(".time").mask("99:99");
    });



if (document.getElementById('form:d').value == 'Date' ||     document.getElementById('form:d').value == '') {
        document.getElementById('form:d').value = 'Date';
    }
    if (document.getElementById('form:t').value == 'Time' || document.getElementById('form:t').value == '') {
        document.getElementById('form:t').value = 'Time';
    }

</script>
```